# Can I PARTITION BY two columns in KSQL

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform

I have two topics users (contains all the users info) and transactions (contains all the transactions made by the users it includes the 'sender' and 'receiver id'), all of my topics data are nested.

First thing I've done was CREATE STREAM, then I CREATED another STREAM to rename those nested fields because PARTITION BY does not accept nested fields somehow, everything works great and my question is that I want to partition transactions per sender and receiver id so I can join it with users does KSQL accepts PARTITION BY two columns? Do I need to PARTITION BY two columns to get this working or do I just need to partition by either sender or receiver?

I have tried this but came back with an error, I also tried to add PARTITION BY (sender, receiver) at the end and came back with a other error

> > ksql> CREATE STREAM transactions WITH (PARTITIONS=1) AS \ SELECT * FROM >>flattentransactions PARTITION BY sender,receiver;
> >     line 1:105: mismatched input ',' expecting ';'
> >     Statement: CREATE STREAM transactions WITH (PARTITIONS=1) AS  SELECT * >>FROM flattentransactions PARTITION BY sender,receiver;
> >     Caused by: line 1:105: mismatched input ',' expecting ';'
> >     Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException ##

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the columns first:

```
CREATE STREAM transactions 
   WITH (PARTITIONS=1) AS 
    SELECT X,Y,Z,SENDER + RECEIVER AS MSG_KEY 
        FROM flattentransactions
    PARTITION BY MSG_KEY
```

Comment: Thank you Robbin, the reason behind my join is to be able to visualize the sender and receiver info inside the transactions, if i would concatenate both sender and receiver i would end up with two id's concatenated as a key and the users table is partitioned by id that way i can not join them with the users table.

Comment: I've end up following this example
1- create stream from users topic,
2-flatten it, 
3-create table out of it with a key, 
4-create stream from transactions topic
5-flatten it
6-assigned the sender key
7-join it with the users table
8-create a other stream from transactions flattened, and assigned the key as receiver this time
9-join it with the users table
10-rekeyed the second transactions stream that is joined with the users table with receiver this time so i can join it with the first join stream from step 7

works but somehow in step 2 and bellow, data started duplicating.